# UserControl not instanciated in main Form Designer

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

In my project, I was adding a UserControl when the user clicks on a button.  Okay fair enough. I decided that I wanted to add a UserControl to the Form in the Designer.
The app starts with at least this one, it cannot be removed, unlike others, programmatically added, UserControls (same UserControl).

My problem  is simple but I don't get why, let most post some code :

The very first time I put the control my main form, all was okay. After compiling the main form could not be displayed because that line was removed, there crashes when setting properties since control is null.
I can add that line manually, compile, it will be removed.

```
this.IntegerControl1= new IntegerControl();

... 

//
// IntegerControl1
// 
this.IntegerControl1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D; <- crashes there
this.IntegerControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 52);
this.IntegerControl1.Name = "IntegerControl1";
this.IntegerControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(325, 53);
this.IntegerControl1.TabIndex = 4;

...

private IntegerControl IntegerControl1;
```

I explained in the first commented out line my problem. Usually I don't use UserControls, I just make a class that inherits from panel and voilà. I don't think code of the UserControl is needed but I could be wrong.

If it's instead needed, let me know and I'll post more code or be more specific!

Comment: Put a break point on the new statement.  Then check the value of BorderStyle on original control.

Comment: Post at least the UserControl constructor (if you don't have an empty constructor, add one). It's not exactly clear whether you're trying to add the Usercontrol to the `designer.cs` file directly. Maybe also specify how/where this UC is defined (e.g., it's a class object in the same project, it's a stand-alone project, it comes from a compiled .dll of an external project)

Comment: I changed the UC constructor from internal (suggested by Reshaper when I had the trial) to public and now it seems that all is fine.

Comment: public IntegerControl () => InitializeComponent(); nothing fancy about the UC constructor. But yes, the problem that I could drag & add the UC to my main form but for some reason, after compiling, properties where set, but the UC it's wasn't getting instiancated, therefore null and crash when afficting properties.